# Первый запуск на данном компьютере

Tags: c#

Как проверить, первый ли раз запускается программа на данном компьютере? К примеру, чтобы зарегистрировать продукт в базе данных

Comment: какая программа?

Comment: Например пишете в реестр какое-то значение и проверяете. Или создаете файл, только это все ненадежные способы.

Comment: Программа ваша или сторонняя запускается?

Answer (score 7):

При первом запуске нужно проставлять где-нибудь флаг о запуске этой программы. Потом, при каждом последующем запуске, этот флаг можно проверять. Где именно хранить такой флаг — зависит от ваших требований и возможностей.

Вот некоторые варианты:

1. Ключ в реестре Windows.
2. Создание файла в каталоге вашего приложения в AppData.
3. В локальной базе данных (если такая имеется).
4. В облаке (или на своих публично доступных серверах), с указанием уникального идентификатора машины.
5. Аппаратный ключ (например, зашифрованный USB stick).

И т.д.

Answer (score 2):

Надёжного пути нет (злонамеренный юзер может подчистить за старой инсталляцией), но рекомендованный путь — использование флага в `Settings`.

Comment: а можно флаг вкомпилить в сборку при запуске? то есть напрямую поменять свой исполняемый код

Comment: Надёжные пути есть — хранение информации в местах, недоступных для изменения пользователю. Это либо сервера в интернете, либо зашифрованная ключ-флешка. Чтобы обойти эти два способа, нужно взламывать сборки приложения; если они обфусцированы, то задача даже для опытного взломщика становится очень сложной. А для рядового пользователя — невыполнимой.
Другое дело — насколько такая надёжность нужна. Тут уже решать может только автор.

Comment: @Grundy: Нет, вы не сможете с правами юзера писать в Program Files.

Comment: @VladD, это если программа в Program Files, и если она не запущена от администратора

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко: Надёжными эти пути всё равно не являются. Пользователь имеет контроль над своей машиной. Против злонамеренного пользователя играть нету смысла, неэтично, подвержено ошибкам, отпугивает добросовестных пользователей и в конечном итоге не способствует получению дохода от продажи программы.

Comment: @VladD скажем так, эти пути более надёжны с точки зрения автора программы, но менее удобны с точки зрения пользователя.

Comment: @Grundy, я точно так же могу поменять руками то, что программа поменяет сама при первом запуске.

Comment: @Grundy: То, что программа находится в недоступном юзеру для записи месте — это типично. А сидеть под администратором, наоборот, нетипично, это ж не 95-ая. Тем более, вы не сможете записать в файл, из которого запущена программа, придётся идти на трюки. Именно поэтому это и не рекомендованный Майкрософтом путь.

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко: Злонамеренный пользователь всё равно не заплатит. Считать, что вы можете принудить пользователя заплатить техническими средствами, оставаясь в рамках закона и этики — наивность.

Comment: @VladD, заставить можно, но часто, чтобы такое решение реализовать нужно заплатить немалую сумму. Есть до сих пор невзломанные игры, насколько я знаю, которые человек будет вынужден купить, если хочет поиграть. Так что решение есть, вопрос лишь в средствах, которые автор готов вложить в защиту.

Comment: @VladD, я с вами согласен в принципе. Но в данном контексте я обсуждаю проблему чисто с технической стороны, т.к. про этику ОП ничего не спрашивал.

Comment: @ixSci: Для этого игра должна быть настолько крута, что её захотят купить невзломанной. Иначе программа будет напоминать неуловимого Джо.

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко: Этика (неявно) важна. Неэтичных способов получить деньги от пользователя много. Да хоть зашифровать все его данные и потребовать выкуп. (Это, конечно, негативно повлияет на продажи. Как и другие неэтичные методы.)

Comment: @ДмитрийШевченко: Впрочем, думаю, у нас консенсус.

Answer (score 1):

> примеру, чтобы зарегистрировать продукт в базе данных

Придумываете способ (гуглите способ) сгенерировать уникальный ID машины, пишете его в базу и проверяете на наличие при запуске.

Если ID в базе нет - поздравляю, это первый запуск.